# MS Graph CalendarView BadRequest

Tags: azure

Can somone tell me why am i getting bad request using this query in powershell script.Authentication with token is working fine and some other query are working with same authentication method.

```
$query = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/resourceMb@company.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-10-03T00:00:00&endDateTime=2023-10-04T00:00:00"
```

$appointments = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($AccessToken)"} -Uri $query -Method Get).Value

Same query is working in graph explorer.

ErrorMessage : Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The ***"400 Bad request"*** error usually occurs if the query you are passing to fetch the data is invalid.

**To fetch the calendar view of the user**, make use of below query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-10-02T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2023-10-03T19:00:00-08:00
```

*As the user in my environment doesn't have any calendar view, I got the empty results:*

[image]

When I tried the same query as you in PowerShell, I got the **same error** like below:

```
$query = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-10-01T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2023-10-02T19:00:00-08:00"
```

[image]

**To resolve the error**, make sure to include **`users`** in the query and modify it like below:

```
$Body = @{
    client_id = "ClientID"
    client_secret = "ClientSecret"
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    grant_type = 'client_credentials'
}
$Connect_Graph = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method Post -Body $Body
$token = $Connect_Graph.access_token
$query = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-10-01T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2023-10-02T19:00:00-08:00"
(Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($token)"} -Uri $query -Method Get).value
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[List calendarView - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

The date and time format looks wrong to me could you pass the format in ISO 8601 format as described [here](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/resourceMb@company.com/calendarView?startDateTime)

Ex: `$query = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/resourceMb@company.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-10-03T00:00:00.000Z&endDateTime=2023-10-04T00:00:00.000Z"`